# Custom annotation injection with Jersey 1.x

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, annotations, jersey

> I am using jersey 1.9.1. I have rest method like following where
>   Authorization header contained encoded credentials  such as username
>   and password and it is parsed in a method and mapped local values.

```
@PUT
@Path(SystemConstants.REST_MESSAGE_SENDSMS)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response sendSms(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization, String param) {

    String[] credentials = ImosUtils.getUserCredentials(authorization);
    String username = credentials[0];
    String password = credentials[1];       
    }
```

I am trying to design a way to make this process automatically, without writing same parsing code in each method. I mean I would like to know if writing a special annotation such as `HeaderParamExtended` to this is used to parse this credentials.
I am using jersey 1.9.1 version as rest api. Where I have to edit a class in that life cycle?

```
@PUT
@Path(SystemConstants.REST_MESSAGE_SENDSMS)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response sendSms(@HeaderParamExtended("Authorization","username") String username, @HeaderParamExtended("Authorization","password") String password, , String param) {


    }
```

Comment: I did something very similar in the recent past (i.e. authenticated services).  I used AspectJ in order not to have the code for authenticating users in each service. I don't know if such an approach can be useful for you, but using an aspect turned out to be a pretty nice solution in my case.

Comment: Can't you add "security" in the web.xml level and the call won't come to your method and gets Authenticated before hand? Or add a filter to your service that intercept and does this authorization part at one place?

Comment: I already have such level to authentıcate but I have to use username per request, so I need to pass it into service level after authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you need an [`InjectableProvider`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider.html) to support the custom injection, and also an [`Injectable`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/Injectable.html) to provide the value.

Here's an example

**`@BasicAuth`**

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BasicAuth {
}
```

**`InjectableProvider`**

```
@Provider
public class BasicAuthInjectionProvider
        implements InjectableProvider<BasicAuth, Parameter> {

    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext cc, BasicAuth a, Parameter c) {
        return new BasicAuthInjectable();
    }
}
```

**`Injectable`**

```
public class BasicAuthInjectable extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<User>{

    @Override
    public User getValue(HttpContext hc) {
        String authHeaderValue = hc.getRequest()
                .getHeaderValue(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        String[] credentials = ImosUtils.getUserCredentials(authHeaderValue);

        return new User(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
    }  
}
```

One thing you'll notice is that I have a `User` class. This is to wrap the `username` and `password`, and just have one injection point. i.e.

```
public Response getSomething(@BasicAuth User user) {
}
```

I actually tried to do it your way, with

```
public Response getSomething(@BasicAuth("username") String username,
                             @BasicAuth("password") String password) {
```

And in the `InjectableProvider` get the annotation value from the annotation passed to the `getInjectable`, then pass that value onto the `BasicAuthInjectable`. From there check to see if the value is `"username"` or `"password"` and return the corresponding value. But for some reason the injection providers were not even called. You can play around with it to see if you can get it to work. But to me the `User` looks cleaner anyway, and with the two strings, the injection providers are called twice and you need to parse the headers twice. Seems unnecessary.

Comment: I am getting following error on deployment ,  com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException:com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.ErrorMessagesException:null

Comment: I tested with 1.19. Let me change it to 1.9.1 and see if I get the same problem.

Comment: Yeah just tested with Jersey 1.9.1. It works fine. If you're not using scanning for your providers and resource classes the `@Provider` annotation won't be picked up, and you need to explicitly register the provider. Maybe that's the problem. Not sure. If you want to create a small Github project that reproduces the problem, I can look at it. Otherwise that snippet of error, is not enough to find the problem.

Comment: I have created sample file but credentialbean does not initialized.   "CredentialBean:  username:null, password:null"  https://www.dropbox.com/s/go13aedpoz0nruu/RESTfulExample.rar?dl=0

Comment: I've tested and it does not give any exceptions on startup. The only problem I faced was fixed by adding the `com.mkyong.auth` package to the list of packages to scan in the web.xml. You only have `com.mkyong.rest` which doesn't include the provider you need. You can add more than one package by a comma delimiter

Comment: Other than that, I would avoid mixing Jersey versions. You are using the 1.18 bundle with jersey-server 1.9. The bundle already includes the classes from `jersey-server` so you can get rid of that.